# Add Custom Button in Attach Items Outlook Addin

Tags: outlook-addin

I need to Add a Custom Button on Click of Attach Items in Outlook Email. Please share the code or share the link to achieve the same.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EJT7.png)

Comment: We don't share code here. We simply help with issues you're having within your own code

Comment: @user2277872: there is nothing wrong with asking for sample code when you don't know how to achieve something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, Also note that in latest versions of Outlook there is no such dropdown - there are separate buttons.